# Mouse buttons on Lenovo X1 tablet w/Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: ubuntu, mouse

I have a fresh install of Ubuntu 20.04 on a Lenovo X1 tablet.  (The one with removable keyboard)

Although multitouch gestures work fine on trackpad and pointer stick works fine, the physical click buttons don't work.  I have to press on the trackpad to left/right click.

Is there a known way to enable the physical buttons?